# I want to upload an audio/text/pdf file using $http post method

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload

I want to upload an audio/txt/pdf file using $http post method.
my html code

```
 <input type="file" id="myFile" size="50"/>
      <button type="button" ng-click="vm.upload()">Upload</button>
```

js page

```
vm.upload =function(){
                var obj= {};
               var x = document.getElementById("myFile").value;     
         obj["fileName"]=x;

    $http({
     method:'POST',
     url:"url",
     data : obj,
     headers:{
         "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream",

     }
 }).then(function(response){

 })
```

here file is uploaded but their is no content.
give me any idea.

Comment: I did not get any answers.\

Comment: can anyone give me an idea?